# How to force a textField to become editable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I guess my description is not clear enough. So I'll try again:

1. Imagine there is a ViewController, called Picture, that display two lines, Title and Description.
2. In case the user tap one of the rows a new view controller is displayed, either Title or Description view controller.
3. Each of these view controllers (i.e. Title or Description) displays a single raw of a custom cell with a UITextField in it.

The Problem:

- Suppose the user types in a Title and hits the Done button ---> The Title is displayed in the Picture view controller. - That's good.
- If I hit the Title row again, the title view controller is displayed but the placeHolder text is shown instead of the title that was previously entered by the user. - that's BAD!

I tried to use [[cell mTitle] setText:picTitle] but it doesn't shown.

Comment: I think you mean UITextField, there is no UITextLabel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a UITextLabel, its not editable.
If you are using a UITextfield it should be editable after setText
If you are using a UITextView, set editable=YES;

Comment: I Use UITextFiled and after the setText its like the text covers the textField. For example, I limit the length of the text for 6 characters. If i try to type something, the text doesn't change but in case I exceed six characters I get an Alert that I launch.

Comment: Now it works. 
I tried to setText form the Cell ([cell setMText:...]) instead of using the delegate function - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField